# unloading the relationships in ember

Tags: ember.js, delete-record

I am developing an app that deals with files.I have a model called file.It has comments model in a has many relationships.Lets say I have a folder F1.F1 contains 3 files and 1 Folder called (F2).F2 has 3 files.Supposing If am deleting F1.The deleteRecord is performed on F1.I can able to unload the model that are in direct relationship with F1.for this I am using cascade-delete mixin.How can I unload the relation ship model that has nested relation ship with F1 such as the files under F2.

model/file.js

```
 export default DS.Model.extend({
      name: DS.attr(),
      comments:('comment', { cascadeDelete: true }
    });
```

mixins/cascade-delete.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  deleteRecord(store, type, snapshot) {
    let recordsToUnload = [];

    // collect all records to unload into recordsToUnload variable
    snapshot.record.eachRelationship((name, descriptor) => {
      let { options, kind } = descriptor;
      let relationshipName = descriptor.key;

      if (options.cascadeDelete && kind === 'hasMany') {
        let hasManyRecords = snapshot.record.hasMany(relationshipName).value();
        if (hasManyRecords !== null) {
          hasManyRecordsArray = hasManyRecords.toArray();
        }
        recordsToUnload = recordsToUnload.concat(hasManyRecords);
      }

      if (options.cascadeDelete && kind === 'belongsTo') {
        let belongsToRecords = snapshot.record.belongsTo(relationshipName).value();
        recordsToUnload = recordsToUnload.concat([ belongsToRecords ]);
      }
    });

    return this._super(...arguments).then((response) => {
      recordsToUnload.forEach((childRecord) => {
        store.unloadRecord(childRecord);
      });

      return response;
    });
  }
});
```